# What's the difference between assigning a string value within and without parentheses for a variable in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
message = "Hello World!"
```

vs

```
message = ("Hello World!")
```

As far as I have tested, both get interpreted with the same output. I've just started to learn python and wondering if those parentheses have any impact.

Comment: They do not (have any impact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the implementations are same.

```
message= "Hello World!"
print(type(message))
```

**Output**: <class 'str'>

```
message = ("Hello World!")
print(type(message))
```

**Output**: <class 'str'>

Adding parenthesis to a string don't automatically make them tuples. You need to add a comma after the string to indicate to python that it should be a tuple.

```
message = ("Hello World!",)
print(type(message))
```

**Output:**<class 'tuple'>

Answer (score 0):

Just like in a mathematical expression, parentheses don't always change the output in Python.

`5 + 4 == (5 + 4) == ((5) + ((4)))`

It isn't necessary to use parentheses to assign values to variables like in your question. In general however, its not always a bad idea to use parentheses even if they don't change the output of the code - if the order of operations is not perfectly clear, parentheses will make it obvious.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the answers above mentioned tuples and you indicated you are new to python; I might add that in python having something to the right of an equals sign in parentheses often indicates you are trying to make a tuple. However a tuple requires at least one comma so the interpreter can figure out you are in fact making a tuple, even with only one entry.

In your example putting a string in parentheses has no effect, and probable should not done just because it would not be expected by other python developers. (Not pythonic)

Comment: Yea... I get it now. Parentheses aren't the norm and I better not use them.
Aso, according to what I read with Googling, Tuples are basically an un-editable, safer version of lists, right?

Comment: Tuples are immutable and are super important in how python works but have some subtleties you should read about.